# When webview and ListView exist in the same view at the same time, how to deal with event blocking?

Tags: flutter, wkwebview, flutter-inappwebview

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iK1Lw.jpg)

In this interface, the black translucent part of the toolbar is the tool layer developed by Flutter, and the white background part is Flutter's inappwebview. We used web canvas to develop the whiteboard function. Currently, two problems are encountered: 1. The touchstart event cannot be triggered in the webview. 2. When you click on Flutter's toolbar (black translucent part) to select a tool, and then click on the white canvas, the first click cannot trigger any events of the webview.

The ListView and webview of the toolbar both belong to the subcomponent of the same View. How to deal with this problem?

Expectations: 1. Touchstart, touchend, and touchmove events can bubble up to the webview correctly.
2. After clicking the ListView selection tool, the next click in the webview can be triggered directly in the webview.